# Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error -excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

VBA code :
Excel
When I run click this error appear
The error : Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

```
Private Sub commandButton1_click()

Dim last As Integer   



last=sheet2.Range("B1000").End(x1Up).Row + 1    
sheet2.Cells(last, "B").Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
sheet2.Cells(last, "C").Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
sheet2.Cells(last, "D").Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
sheet2.Cells(last, "E").Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
sheet2.Cells(last, "F").Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
sheet2.Cells(last, "G").Value = Me.TextBox6.Value
sheet2.Cells(last, "H").Value = Me.TextBox7.Value 
sheet2.Cells(last, "I").Value = Me.TextBox8.Value  
Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
Me.TextBox2.Value = ""
Me.TextBox3.Value = ""
Me.TextBox4.Value = ""
Me.TextBox5.Value = ""
Me.TextBox6.Value = ""
Me.TextBox7.Value = ""
Me.TextBox8.Value = ""
MsgBox "Saved Successfuly", vbInformation
listsource    

End Sub
```

Comment: A guess would be that one textbox is missing or has a different name than you think. Or that sheet2 does not exist

Comment: You need `Option Explicit` at the top of the module to flag the undeclared variable `x1Up`, which should be `xlUp`... the letter `l` as in `lambda`, not the number `1`.

Answer (score 0):

last = (Sheet2.Range("B1000").End(xlUp).Row) + 1